# How to get values for multiple keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get values using multiple keys.
I have a php code that works for single key but i want to get values for multiple keys. How can i do that?

```
<?php
$arr=array(
'1'=>'India',
'2'=>'Canada',
'3'=>'United',
'4'=>'China',
'5'=>'London',
'6'=>'New Delhi',
);

$key1='4';
$key2='3';
$key3='4';
echo $arr[$key1, $key2, $key3];

?>
```

I want output like this in proper order

```
China
United
China
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try.. umm.. echo'ing them individually? This is currently invalid syntax

Comment: You must echo $arr[$key1], then echo $arr[$key2], then echo $arr[$key3]. This is not Matlab or Sas. You can't pass a vector as an index.

Comment: `echo $arr[$key1], $arr[$key2], $arr[$key3];` ?

Comment: Thanks bro! can we define all keys in single line something like this $key='4','3','4'; and get output like this eho $arr[$key];

Comment: @GopalMeena No. As mentioned above, the key CANNOT be a vector of indexes. It must be a SINGLE index.

Comment: Thanks @kainaw How to use line break ? \r\n, \n, <br \> not working

Comment: In the PHP code you can do `PHP_EOL` - did you looked at my answer?

Comment: @GopalMeena Update your question, showing the code you are using. Then, a suggestion can be made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have interface ArrayAccess in PHP: 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

So we can write code as following to support multiple keys( Updated the example from above page ):
You will have to update it to fit your requirements.

```
<?php

class MultipleKeyArray implements ArrayAccess {

    private $container = array();
    private $separator = ',';

    public function __construct($arr ) {
        $this->container = $arr;
    }

    public function setSeparator($str){
        $this->separator = $str;
    }

    public function offsetSet($offsets, $values) {
        $os = explode(',',$offsets);
        $vs = explode(',',$values);
        $max = max(count($os),count($vs));
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
          $offset = $os[$i];
          $value  = $vs[$i];
          if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
          } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
          }
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offsets) {
        $os = explode(',',$offsets);
        for($i=0;$i<count($os);$i++){
            $offset = $os[$i];
            if( !isset($this->container[$offset]) ){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offsets) {
        $os = explode(',',$offsets);
        for($i=0;$i<count($os);$i++){
          $offset = $os[$i];
          unset($this->container[$offset]);
        }
    }

    public function offsetGet($offsets) {
        $os = explode(',',$offsets);
        $result = '';
        for($i=0;$i<count($os);$i++){
          $offset = $os[$i];
          $result .= ($i>0 ? $this->separator:'') . (isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : '');
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

$arr=array(
    '1'=>'India',
    '2'=>'Canada',
    '3'=>'United',
    '4'=>'China',
    '5'=>'London',
    '6'=>'New Delhi',
);

$o = new MultipleKeyArray($arr);
$o[] = 'new0';
$o['f,g']='new1,new2';

var_dump(isset($o['f,g']));
var_dump(isset($o['1,2,f']));
var_dump(isset($o['f,not,there']));

echo $o['4,3,4']."\n";
echo $o['2,f,g']."\n";

$o->setSeparator("|");
echo $o['4,3,4']."\n";
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
China,United,China
Canada,new1,new2
China|United|China
```

Comment: Nice one! +1. I recommend use the separator also in the input and keys as someone may want to do `echo $o['4|3|4']."\n";`

Comment: Thank you so much @hytest bro!

Answer (score 1):

PHP index cannot take array - you should do that with loop or PHP array function.

First define array of the key you need as:

```
$keys = [$key1, $key2, $key3];
```

Now use a `foreach` loop to echo them as:

```
foreach($keys as $k)
    echo $arr[$k] . PHP_EOL;
```

And the one-liner:

```
array_walk($keys, function($k) use ($arr) {echo $arr[$k] . PHP_EOL;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-line function to filter an array by a list of keys:

```
function pick(array $array, array $keys): array
{
    return array_intersect_key($array, array_fill_keys($keys, 0));
}
```