# can not use object XXX of type as array

Tags: php, arrays, class, phpunit

I'm running function which throws an error:

> can not use object Coalition/ConfigRepository of type as array

For solving that I need to change in extended class 'ConfigRepository'

```
<?php

use Coalition\ConfigRepository;

class ConfigRepositoryTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
public function test_array_access_set()
    {
        $config = new ConfigRepository;

        $config['foo'] = 'bar'; //throw error here
        $this->assertTrue(isset($config['foo']));
        $this->assertEquals('bar', $config['foo']);
    }
}
public function test_array_access_unset()
    {
        $config = new ConfigRepository(['foo' => 'bar']);
        unset($config['foo']);

        $this->assertFalse($config->has('foo'));
    }
```

Extended class is where i have to change is

```
namespace Coalition;

class ConfigRepository
{
    private $key=[];
    /**
     * ConfigRepository Constructor
     */
    public function __construct($key = null)
    {
       $this->key = $key;
    }
    public function has($key)
    {
      if(!$this->key) return false;
      return array_key_exists($key,$this->key);
    }
}
```

How can I solved it?

Maybe problem is in `__construct` where I have to pass array value?

Comment: The error is clear - object is not array. What do you try to achieve?  do you want the ConfigRepository to hold associative array? And if `$key` is private you should have at least  `get ` method (if not also set / append)

Comment: I want to solve this error for that i have to change in below class and value should be array please update answer by change class Config repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esaiest way to fix will be to make `$key` member public. So first change is in `class ConfigRepository`:

```
public $key=[];
```

Then you can do:

```
public function test_array_access_set() {
    $config = new ConfigRepository(array("foo" => "bar")); // set the value in the constructor 

    // access the $config->key as you array and check what you need
    $this->assertTrue(isset($config->key['foo'])); 
    $this->assertEquals('bar', $config->key['foo']);
}
```

If all you can change is the ConfigRepository calss you should do:

```
class ConfigRepository implements ArrayAccess {

    private $container = array();

    public function __construct($arr ) {
        $this->container = $arr;
    }

   public function offsetExists($offset) {
       return isset($this->container[$offset]);
   }

   public function offsetGet($offset) {
       return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
   }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) 
            $this->container[] = $value;
        else
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

}
```

Comment: i can not change in test_array_access_set() function instead i have to change ConfigRepository class only

Comment: So you rather change the class than the object?? that weird... In that case look at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php on how to implement array-like objects (and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566262/how-to-get-values-for-multiple-keys)

Comment: YEs i have passed all these methods already, just this one is not working

Comment: @KetanBorada This is link for full example: https://3v4l.org/4qbTg. I don't know how more can I help - maybe you issue is elsewhere.

Comment: ArrayAccess  is a key for success